# asp mvc a long initial load of the site (fttb)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

the first time the site is loaded, the site is loaded for a very long time, then the pages are loaded quickly. How can this be corrected?
The iis server and the mssql server are on the same subnet, but on different virtual machines
Each server has 8 GB of RAM and 4 processor cores
No users, these are test machines
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF1Lv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very common issue with all `ASP.NET` application hosted on IIS server, you can check following things for better first time performance improvement.

1. Make sure that the Application Pools is configured as "Always
   Running"
2. Configure IIS Warm-up services for your website
3. Precompile your views